# Allowing apostrophes in the HTML input field

Tags: java, regex

I have a `php code` as shown below which validates the answer at `Line A` which user enters in a html form.

When user enters any answer with apostrophe in the html input field form, I am getting the error message `Secret Answer is Invalid`.
For example: On entering `Hello World'`, I am getting the error message `Secret Answer is Invalid` from Line Z.

```
//response
$response_error = new error();
$response_error->field = SECRET_response;
if($response != "" && $service->validAnswer($answer) != 'true'){   // Line A
    $response_error->inError = true;
    $response_error->errorMessage = SECRET_response.ISINVALID; // Line Z
} else {
    $response_error->inError = false;
}
```

The Java `code/method` belonging to the `validAnswer` method used at `Line A` above is:

```
public static boolean validAnswer(String answer) {
    Pattern a = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\S)[a-zA-Z0-9éèàêâçîëïÇÉÔÂÊÎÔÛËÏÀùÙ!#%&$%*\\- ]+$"); // Line B
    Matcher b = a.matcher(answer);

    logger.info("validAnswer: mmatches(): " + (b.matches()) + " a: " + a);

    return b.matches();
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the `java code` above so that it takes apostrophe in the html input form.

**This is what I have tried in the Java code:**
I have put ' in at the end of [ ] inside of it. On trying that, it doesn't seem to work.

```
public static boolean validAnswer(String answer) {
    Pattern a = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\S)[a-zA-Z0-9éèàêâçîëïÇÉÔÂÊÎÔÛËÏÀùÙ!#%&$%*\\-' ]+$"); // Line A
    Matcher b = a.matcher(answer);

    logger.info("validAnswer: mmatches(): " + (b.matches()) + " a: " + a);

    return b.matches();
}
```

Comment: So you are not seeking a php solution, but a java solution, correct?

Comment: I am bit confused whether I need to make changes in the `Java` or `php`. I believe its java that's why I made changes in the Java code because I am seeing a pattern there but it didn't work

Comment: so.. is this question about [tag:regex]? i can't see any regex tag..

Comment: @BagusTesa Where can I find regex tag ? Am I missing anything ?

Comment: i think your problem is regex. try adding another ``\`` before the `-`  near your aposthrope (`'`). thing is, `-` gotta be escaped otherwise it means range. i tried to copy paste your regex to regex101 it throws an error saying "Character range is out of order."

Comment: like this ?

`Pattern a = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\S)[a-zA-Z0-9éèàêâçîëïÇÉÔÂÊÎÔÛËÏÀùÙ!#%&$%*\\'-' ]+$"); `// Line A

Comment: @BagusTesa I am wondering if you can explain in an answer then that would be great.

Comment: How (and why) are you calling Java from PHP?

Comment: @flash on a second thought, your regex seems alright. i guess you have http/servlet filter or something on the java side to prevent sql injection - assuming you invoke the code via http requests. i reckon some people did exactly that (preventing aposthrope) in any form submission to "prevent" sql injection.

Comment: @BagusTesa

**1. With apostrophe (Before):** https://onecompiler.com/java/3ycmmjebu 

**2. Without apostrophe (After my changes):** https://onecompiler.com/java/3ycpta99j When you say your regex , you mean after the changes I made ?

Comment: @flash regex refers to regular expression. the thing you have in `Pattern.compile(...)`.

Answer (score 11):

Calling Java from PHP just to use a regex is very weird and inefficient. PHP has regex support of course, so you don't need Java for that.

Anyway, your latest code works perfectly:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
    public static boolean validAnswer(String answer)
    {
        Pattern a = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\S)[a-zA-Z0-9éèàêâçîëïÇÉÔÂÊÎÔÛËÏÀùÙ!#%&$%*\\-' ]+$");
        Matcher b = a.matcher(answer);
        return b.matches();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(validAnswer("Hello World'"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

So I guess you didn't recompile your code after modifying it.